# Different scenarios with Slowly Changing Dimensions (SCD) Type 2

Tags: sql, etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

We currently have a table in the data warehouse named 'Cards'. This was designed as a slowly changing dimension of type 2; where we create a new record should the card state change so that we can keep track of the state changes of the card.

We are also keeping a daily record for each card, even if no state changed - this is done to keep track of the daily balance. Example:

```
cardId     state          balanceAsAt     balance  ....
1          ACTIVE         2014-01-01      100.00
1          ACTIVE         2014-01-02       99.00
1          DELETED        2014-01-03        0.00
```

What is the optimal way to store data should I need to execute the ETL for a past date range (e.g. 2nd January 2014) today, Feb 2015 (example for 2014-01-01), assuming there is no way to retrieve the past state of the card?

Option A - insert a record with the current data for the past day

```
cardId     state          balanceAsAt     balance  ....
1          ACTIVE         2014-01-01      100.00
1          DELETED        2014-01-01        0.00   [new entry here? - however now the card seems to have been 're-activated' on the 2nd, which is not the case]
1          ACTIVE         2014-01-02       99.00
1          DELETED        2014-01-03        0.00
```

Option B - do not modify records already created in the dimension

```
cardId     state          balanceAsAt     balance  ....
1          ACTIVE         2014-01-01      100.00
1          ACTIVE         2014-01-02       99.00
1          DELETED        2014-01-03        0.00
```

Any other options/standard practices?

Comment: I don't understand the problem - what do you mean by `execute past ETL today, Feb 2015`? Why do you insert additional row for 2014-01-01?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say what the options are should I execute the ETL for a past date range (e.g. 2014-01-01) - should we include a new record because of the updated card state?

Answer (score 2):

After reading the description, I realized you might have in hands a very fast changing dimension. My proposal it would be if possible, **change the balance attribute to slow changing dimensions type 1 (update), and keep record of the balances in a fact table**. For this you have two options:

1. snapshot: for each day is created an entry for each card. This is very good for example, if you need to know (frequently) what was the average balance balance of the cards in a given day (or during a given month).
2. transaction logging: a fact table where you keep track the transactions on the card, and the balance before and after the transaction. This have the advantage of the snapshot of take less space in the hard drive.

You should be aware that using **Slow Changing Dimensions** should be used for attributes that change slowly, and use slow changing dimensions for attributes that change very often is not a good idea. You will have your cards dimensions growing too fast; and this will carry a performance burden.

---

My second note is that you are not implementing the Slow Changing Dimensions properly. You neither implementing dimensional keys, neither Slow Changing Dimensions flags.

A properly implemented dimension would look like this:

```
keyCard   cardId         state          startDate       endDate      balance  
1          1          ACTIVE         2014-01-01     2014-01-03   100.00
2          1          ACTIVE         2014-01-03     2014-02-01   99.00
3          1          DELETED        2014-02-01     null          0.00
```

You can retrieve the last record by doing a:

```
  select * from DimensionCards where endDate is null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes of course I only included the necessary fields. I do have a start and end date together with a flag cardIsActive which is TRUE when I have the latest version for that card.